# How to recollect memory after Control + C force quit

Tags: c, terminal, server

I am running a C program in terminal.

I have created linked type using **malloc**. I understand I should use **free** to recollect memory. If I have to use Control + C to stop the process. What is the right method to recollect memory space?

Or what is the right way to do server debugging without memory leakage?

Background:
I am writing a server in C. If no error happens, it is assumed to run forever until I force stop it.

Comment: I would have assumed that the operating system would handle this, but it's always better to try and free the memory yourself.

Comment: The operating system will `free` memory you've allocated when your process terminates. However, you can write a [signal handler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling) if you need to close some external resources if the process terminates.